# Single-User Mode in Windows?

Tags: windows

I've used Single-User Mode on my Mac and I find it quite useful and educational. Is there a Windows equivalent?

Part of the reason I want a Windows equivalent is because from Single-User Mode, I was able to reset the admin password and regain control of the computer. I'd like to see if I can replicate this effect on my PC.

Comment: Well, it could be argued that Safemode is the Windows approach to SU mode, but no, there is no way to boot into a session as NT Authority\System.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows is built somewhat completely different to mac/linux and there is no real single user mode.

If you need to reset an administrator account, there are a couple of things you can try:

1)Reboot your computer and as your BIOS screen shows, keep tapping F8 on your keyboard.  This will bring up a menu option list - one of which will be "Safe Mode".  From here you should be able to login and change an administrators password.  The easiest way to do this is to load C:\windows\system32\lusrmgr.msc and find your user.

2)Look at some offline password editors.  Some of the most commonly used ones are mtnioned in [this article](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/tp/passrecovery.htm) and include:

1. ophCrack
2. Offline NT Password & Registry Editor
3. PC Login Now
   ..and many more

3)look into the possibility of resetting your computer - this is a bit more extreme and will reset windows to its "out of the box" settings... including removal of user passwords.  This, however, also removes user accounts, apps, data as well - only really to be used as a last resort and only if you have a recent data backup.  To complete the Reset Your PC process, [access Advanced Startup Options](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/open-advanced-startup-options-windows-8.htm) and then choose Troubleshoot -> Reset Your PC.

Comment: I'm trying to use ophCrack, but it seems to require the password, which I don't have. I only have passwords to non-administrator accounts right now.

Comment: "somewhat completely" Well, that says it all. :)

Answer (score 1):

There really is no equivalent mode in Windows, Safe Mode does allow for some system recovery options as does a repair disc. If the hard drive is unencrypted however, it is trivial to remove/change a local machine account's (yes even administrator) password from a boot disc or thumb drive. Look for Offline NT Password and Registry Editor, I believe it is packaged into the Ultimate Boot CD as well. Please be aware that you can seriously break things if you use these tools and don't pay attention to what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to a (single user mode) if you want a text-based system for commands to be entered than use "safe mode with command prompt"